# NHibernate 4.0 code mapping with intentional duplicate import

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How can I get this working using only NHibernate 4.0 and [CoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)?

I need to map two different classes that share the same name:

```
namespace MyApp.VersionA {
    public class User{
    //omitted properties
    }
}
namespace MyApp.VersionB {
    public class User{
    //omitted properties
    }
}
```

This is my NHibernate setup method:

```
var config = new Configuration();
config.Configure();
var mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.AddMappings(GetAllMappingTypes());
config.AddMapping(mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities());
config.BeforeBindMapping += (sender, args) => args.Mapping.autoimport = false;
Factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Notice that I set up autoimport=false, but I still get an DuplicateMappingException from NHibernate:

> nhibernate.duplicatemappingexception: duplicate import:
>   User refers to both
>   MyApp.VersionA,
>   ... and
>   MyApp.VersionB.User,
>   ... (try using auto-import="false")

Comment: @timss thanks for formatting it properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexander, try this:

```
        var assemblies =
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => a.GetName().Name.Contains(".Infrastructure"));
        foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
        {
            var mapper = new ModelMapper();
            mapper.AddMappings(assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(t => t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
                            t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (ClassMapping<>)));

            var compileMapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
            compileMapping.autoimport = false;

            configuration.AddMapping(compileMapping);
        }
```